Applying Integration by parts to the Dirac Delta Sifting Property
I've seen explanations/proofs of the dirac delta sifting property which involve treating the given function as a constant close to the impulse point, but I wanted to try and prove it using regular integral manipulation, using integration by parts and the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\delta(x)dx} = 1$. I'll use $0$ as the impulse point for simplicity.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)\delta(x)dx} = \Big[f(x)\Big]^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{df}{dx}dx} = \Big[f(x)\Big]^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \Big[f(x)\Big]^{\infty}_{-\infty} = 0
$$
So here we can see it seems to be $0$, contrary to the correct result which is $f(0)$. So my question here is: is this just a case of "well it's not continuous or even well defined as a function so it's illegal to use integration by parts, fullstop", or is there something I've gotten wrong with the bounds? this work in an intuitive way? (even if it's not entirely formal).
Thanks, any answers are greatly appreciated :)

Explain your first equality $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)\delta(x)dx} = \Big[f(x)\Big]^{\infty}{-\infty}-\int{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{df}{dx}dx}$$

If we define $H(x)$ as the step function so that $H'(x) = \delta(x)$ in some weak sense so that $H(x) = 0$ when $x < 0$ and assume that $f$ and its derivatives decay sufficiently fast, then integration by parts reads as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\delta(x)~dx &= \lim_{a,b\to\infty}\left[f(x)H(x)\right]_{-a}^b - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)H(x)~dx \\
&= \lim_{b\to\infty} f(b) - \lim_{c\to\infty}\int_0^c f'(x)~dx \\
&= \lim_{b\to\infty} f(b) - \left(\lim_{c\to\infty} f(c) - f(0)\right) \\
&=f(0).
\end{aligned}
$$

Ahh thanks, that really clear's things up!
